# Ruby on Rails - ActiveAdmin - Configuring Utility Navigation when default_namespace = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So, I have been working with Ruby on Rails and ActiveAdmin for a while now, but it seems that I might be missing something basic...

I want to have my own Utility Navigation in my application, sounds easy enough, there is some documentation pointing to this on the main [ActiveAdmin documentation page](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#utility_navigation).

Makes sense, and should probably simple enough...

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info", html_options: { target: :blank }
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu # can also pass priority & html_options for link_to to use
    end
  end
end
```

BUT, I have...

```
config.default_namespace = false
```

which sort of turns off the

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
```

bit of code.

My assumption was to just go back to using the standard non-namespace version for configuration, much like so many other parts of the configuration system and just use.

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
    menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info", html_options: { target: :blank }
    config.add_logout_button_to_menu menu # can also pass priority & html_options for link_to to use
  end
end
```

BUT, of course I get `undefined method 'build_menu'`.

So, I have to assume that I am missing something simple, and at the moment I am not sure what that simple thing is.

If anyone out there has any suggestions, please let me know.

Mark,

Answer (score 4):

In this case you should be able to use the :root namespace.

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :root do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info", html_options: { target: :blank }
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu # can also pass priority & html_options for link_to to use
    end
  end
end
```